# Cohort based on week and month from UNIX timestamp

Tags: r, time, dplyr, timestamp, lubridate

I need to extract the calendarweek+year and month+year to indicate cohorts in my data.

Example data:

```
da = data.frame(start_timestamp = c("1453598257", "1434619797","2016-02-23"))
da
  start_timestamp
1      1453598257
2      1434619797
3      1456324104
```

I would like to add the following variables:

1. startcalendarweek: indicates the calendarweek + year of the start_timestamp
2. startmonth: indicates the month + year of the start_timestamp
3. cohort_startweek: indicates the cohort based on the startcalendarweek (1 = calendar week 1 in 2015, 2 = calendar week 2 in 2015 etc.)
4. cohort_startmonth: indicates the cohort based on the startmonth (1 = January 2015, 2 = February 2015 etc.)

Outout data:

```
da
  start_timestamp startcalendarweek   startmonth cohort_startweek cohort_startmonth
1      1453598257            4_2016  january2016               55                13
2      1434619797           25_2015     june2015               24                 6
3      1456324104            8_2016 february2016               60                14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following using `lubridate` functions :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
da = data.frame(start_timestamp = c("1453598257", "1434619797","1456324104"))  

da %>%
  mutate(start_timestamp = as_datetime(as.numeric(start_timestamp)), 
         date = as.Date(start_timestamp), 
         startcalendarweek = format(date, '%V_%Y'), 
         startmonth = format(date, '%B%Y'), 
         min_date = floor_date(min(date), 'year'),
         cohort_startweek = as.integer(round(difftime(date, min_date, units = 'week'))), 
         cohort_startmonth = as.integer(round((date - min_date)/30)))
```

You can look up `?strptime` to know what each value in `format` means. `cohort_startmonth` might not be exact since I am dividing by 30 here to get difference in month (number of days in a month is not always 30).